# Using vi mode in readline/bash appears to break history-search

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, vi, readline

I'm very fond of using readline's `history-search-forward` and `history-search-backward` with bash. I have the following in my `.inpurc`:

```
# Scroll through matching history with up and down keys
"\e[A":history-search-backward
"\e[B":history-search-forward
```

and use the up and down keys to scroll through matching commands in my history.

However, when I enable vi-mode, it seems to stop the history search working. I have vi-mode configured thusly (also in `.inputrc`):

```
# Enable vi mode
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-command

# insert/command mode indicator:
set show-mode-in-prompt on

# Indicator formatting in prompt:
set vi-cmd-mode-string "\1\e[0;34m\2[\1\e[0m\2C\1\e[0;34m\2]\1\e[0m\2 "
set vi-ins-mode-string "\1\e[0;34m\2[\1\e[0m\2I\1\e[0;34m\2]\1\e[0m\2 "
```

When I remove the vi-mode related lines from my `.inputrc`, history search works fine. When I put them back, it breaks.

Is there a way to enable both features simultaneously?

I'm using GNU Bash 4.4.12 installed through homebrew on OSX Sierra.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is not a programming question, and so would be more appropriate at [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me in `vi-insert` mode:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-insert
    "\e[A":history-search-backward
    "\e[B":history-search-forward
```

Or you can write this in the `bashrc`:

```
set -o vi
bind -m vi-insert '"\e[A":history-search-backward'
bind -m vi-insert '"\e[B":history-search-forward'
```